# Want To Stop Using .ruby-version In My Rails Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rvmrc

When I first started writing Rails applications I used .ruby-version because I read about it on the RVM website.  I did this for two of my Rails applications.  It was so long ago that I do not remember the commands that I typed to activate this.  I have seven other applications where I do not use .ruby-version nor .rvmrc.  All I did was assign a gemset (rvm use) to the application and they are working just fine.

Here is my situation.  On my development server I was able to change the gemset to the one I want to use by doing rvm use 1.9.3@gemsetname --default.  Once I did that I did a bundle update to make sure no gems were missing in the gemset.  Afterwards I am still able to run the application.  I then deleted the gemset that was in the .ruby-version.  After deploying the application I am still able to use the website with no problem.  However there is a different story on my production server.  I can go through the same steps on the production server, including deleting the .ruby-version file, but somehow it still looks for the gem file that was in the deleted .ruby-version file.  When I put the .ruby-version file back in the application I have to do a bundle update to install all the gems into the gemset that I attempted to delete.  I'm sure there is something that I did on the production server that I must not have done on the development server that is causing this.

I want to change the two applications where it does not use .ruby-version at all like the other applications.  My goal is to have one gemset for all my applications using the latest version of Rails 3.2 and to eventually create a second gemset for all Rails 4.0 applications.

I have tried to do a search on .ruby-version in Stack Overflow but cannot find any relevant posts about this.  Maybe I'm just having a bad day because I'm sure someone has posted something about this over the years.  I have tried to find the page where .ruby-version is discussed on the RVM website but cannot find it.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 7/22 9:22 am CDT 0915 GMT-5**

I remembered that on my development server I did the command below in preparation to eventually upgrade Ruby to Ruby 2.0.

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
gem update bundler
```

I had not done this on my production server.  I just did both of these commands, selected the gemset I want to use then deleted the .ruby-version file.  The application did not work.  When I put the file back my application worked.  When I do **rvm gemset list** it says it's using the gemset that I want to use in the future.  Somehow I was able to get rid of the requirement for .ruby-version on my development server but not on my production server.

Here is the problem.  This is what is contained in my .ruby-version file:

```
1.9.3@gemsetname
```

There was logic on the RVM website to set .ruby-version.  I guess I had not set a gemset to use for the application so the system created a gemset with the name of my Rails application.  I should have stated this earlier.  I do not want the application to use the gemsetname it created.

Comment: what ruby server do you use? most likely you have configured it to use the other ruby or did not restart the server properly.

Comment: I'm still running 1.9.3.  I realize that I should not have used .ruby-version before so for my other applications I did not use it.  All I am doing is selecting the gemset I want for them.  They are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.ruby-version` with gemsets - which is possible in rvm but not recommended, there is a separate file for the gemset: `.ruby-gemset` and you should use this file for gemsets and leave `.ruby-version` just for ruby version - which is recommended to keep in you code repository - for more details check this question: [Should I check in `.ruby-gemset` and/or `.ruby-version`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16087120/497756) along with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738020/497756

Comment: I just added more information to my question.  I had read the link you have in your comments but could not find it again.  I have a little knowledge about RVM but not enough to understand 'checking in'.  I have several Rails applications that are not using .ruby-version or .ruby-gemset (a new term for me).  All I do is set the gemset using rvm use 1.9.3@mygemsetname --default.  They are running just fine.  Is there a way to just stop the use of .ruby-version?  Somehow I was able to do this on my development server.  Looks like it happened by accident.