# Should I include .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset when deploying a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rvm

I just followed this [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) install/setup tutorial, which uses **RVM** and creates a **.ruby-version** and a **.ruby-gemset** to specify the Ruby version and a project-specific gemset.

I already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738020/2745495) regarding on what to do to these files for version control.

My question is how about when deploying to hosting platforms, like **Heroku**? They point to your git repository which may or may not include these files. Is it still OK to check-in **.ruby-version** when deploying?

For example, the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) says the the Ruby version is specified via Gemfile or environment variable. So I'm a little confused if platforms like Heroku  respect these RVM-generated files.

Notes:

- Ruby v2.2.3
- RVM v1.26.11

Comment: I don't think heroku will pay any attention to gemset specifications -- your gemset isn't on heroku, so a name of a gemset doesn't mean anything. You don't need it to, if you're using bundler (Which you are if you're using Rails). Your Gemfile.lock does everything a gemset needs to do for heroku deploy, specifying exactly what version of what gems need to be installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087120/should-i-check-in-ruby-gemset-and-or-ruby-version?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) Heroku will look for your Ruby version in a few places:
1) Gemfile
2) An environment variable called CUSTOM_RUBY_VERSION

I prefer to specify the Ruby version in my Gemfile.

So, Heroku should ignore .ruby-version. The Ruby you specify in your Gemfile should probably match the version specified in .ruby-version

As a general rule I would check .ruby-version into source control.

Comment: OK. So I guess there's really two files that specify the ruby version: .ruby-version for the local/team env, and the Gemfile for the production env (Heroku). I'm taking your advice to keep them matched. Thanks!